# Is $f_{n}\left(x\right)=\sin\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{n}\right)$ uniformly convergent on $\left[0,\:2\pi\right]$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Is $f_{n}\left(x\right)$ uniformly convergent on $\left[0,\:2\pi\right]$?
\begin{equation}
f_{n}\left(x\right)=\sin\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{n}\right)
\end{equation}
We can see that $f_{n}\left(x\right)$ converges to $f\left(x\right)=\sin\left(x\right)$
point-wise.

Then how to proceed? 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in\left[0,\:2\pi\right]}\left|\sin\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{n}\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right|
\end{equation}

And hint? or there is another way without using $\lim\sup$ ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Use the inequality
$$\left\vert \sin\left(x+\dfrac{x^2}{n}\right) -\sin x \right\vert \le \dfrac{x^2}{n}\le \dfrac{4\pi^2}{n}$$ and the RHS converges to zero with $n \to \infty$ independently of $x$.

Comment: it is about uniformly continuous, i do not understand how to use it to show converges uniformly

Comment: Use the MVT (and $\vert \sin'(\xi) \vert = \vert \cos(\xi) \vert \leq 1$) , then you even get that the function is lipschitz (with lipschitz constant equal 1).

Comment: @Lithium Sorry, I was too fast. Second part of my answer is correct. I’ll erase the first part.

Comment: oh i did not know that inequality

Comment: $\vert \sin a - \sin b \vert \le \vert a- b\vert$ in general. To prove it you can either use the MVT or the difference of sines as a product of trigonometric functions.

Comment: and can be proved by using mean value theorem ?

Comment: Indeed. MVT = Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: yes that inequality is the key thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use that

$$\sin\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{n}\right)=\sin x\cos \dfrac{x^2}{n}+\cos x\sin \dfrac{x^2}{n}.$$

Thus

\begin{align}\left|\sin\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{n}\right)-\sin x\right|&= \left|sin x\cos \dfrac{x^2}{n}+\cos x\sin \dfrac{x^2}{n}-\sin x\right| \\ &\le |\sin x|\left|1-\cos\dfrac{x^2}{n}\right|+|\cos x|\left|\sin\frac{x^2}{n}\right|.\end{align}

Now using that

$$|\sin t|\le t, |1-\cos t|\le t, \forall t\in [0,\infty),$$

we get

$$\left|\sin\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{n}\right)-\sin x\right|\le \dfrac{x^3}{n}+\dfrac{x^2}{n}=\dfrac{4\pi^2(2\pi+1)}{n}, \forall x\in[0,2\pi],\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$$

So, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\ge \dfrac{4\pi^2(2\pi+1)}{n}$ such that

$$n\ge N\implies\left|\sin\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{n}\right)-\sin x\right|\le\epsilon, \forall x\in[0,2\pi],\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$$